# Cassandra Integration with Apache Spark

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I am trying to run the code provided in the following link:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/accessing-cassandra-from-spark-in-java

Code provided below:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;

public class JavaDemo implements Serializable {
    private transient SparkConf conf;

    private JavaDemo(SparkConf conf) {
        this.conf = conf;
    }

    private void run() {
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        generateData(sc);
        compute(sc);
        showResults(sc);
        sc.stop();
    }

    private void generateData(JavaSparkContext sc) {

        CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(sc.getConf());

        try (Session session = connector.openSession()) {
            session.execute("DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS java_api");
            session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE java_api WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1}");
            session.execute("CREATE TABLE java_api.products (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, parents LIST<INT>)");
            session.execute("CREATE TABLE java_api.sales (id UUID PRIMARY KEY, product INT, price DECIMAL)");
            session.execute("CREATE TABLE java_api.summaries (product INT PRIMARY KEY, summary DECIMAL)");
        }
    }

    private void compute(JavaSparkContext sc) {
    }

    private void showResults(JavaSparkContext sc) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("Java API demo");
        conf.setMaster("local");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "XX.XX.XX.XX");

        JavaDemo app = new JavaDemo(conf);
        app.run();

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {<Cassandra IP>}:9042<
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:176)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:162)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:162)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:73)
    at JavaDemo.generateData(JavaDemo.java:28)
    at JavaDemo.run(JavaDemo.java:18)
    at JavaDemo.main(JavaDemo.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contact points contain multiple data centers:
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.init(LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala:47)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1024)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:270)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:169)
```

Is there something I can do about it. I have tried running Java connection with Cassandra, that seems to be working fine

Comment: The exception looks pretty clear to me: " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contact points contain multiple data centers" - change your `conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "XX.XX.XX.XX");` to the right `YY.YY.YY.YY`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried changing to  a different working IP which connects using a simple Cassandra Java driver. Getting the same error. Do we need ny configuration change to resolve : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contact points contain multiple data centers

Comment: Interesting... looks like it's the config that comes back from cassandra that gives that error. Is your cluster multi DC? Try asking that question on https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/spark-connector-user

Comment: No i have a single data center added  

>>nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                                         Rack
UN  xx.xx.xx.xx  138.48 KB  256     ?       XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-X      rack1
Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted the project into a Maven Project, and tried running, this somehow resolved the issue. Cassandra version used: 2.1.2. I assume it is a version mismatch issue

POM.xml content provided below

```css
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
       <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.0-rc3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
       <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.0-rc3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```